# CDR Reports show names, not numbers

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

In freePBX, what is the correct process of enabling CID Superfecta with "GoogleContacts" so that CDR reports show names instead of numbers? This is what I did so far:

- I created a new Scheme in CID Superfecta and enabled “GoogleContacts”
- Added a few contacts in the Gmail account
- I Debug/Test Run the Scheme and it resolves phone numbers to names as    expected
- I enabled superfecta Lookup in the inbound route.

The problem is that in CDR reports, incoming calls still show up as numbers. Are there any additional configuration steps for this feature to work?

Answer (score 0):

CDR have two columns that can be used to  "show names"

1) callerid(name). You can setup CIDSuprfetch for change on INCOMING calls callerid(name) to any value, based on sql query.

2) accountcode. You can setup for each extension own accountcode, can be anything including name. Will work for OUTBOUND.

In some asterisk's version callerid(name) changes AFTER start of call - ignored. If so, you can patch dialplan for change Accountcode or userfield instead. For that need special knowledge, hire asterisk expert.